# How can I specify a generator and factor using the FrF2 or qualityTools package in R?

Tags: r, statistics, static-methods, experimental-design

How can I specify a generator and factor using the `FrF2` or `qualityTools` package in `R`?

The fractional factorial [experiment](http://gheshlaghi.profcms.um.ac.ir/imagesm/324/stories/Statfolder/Tutorials/tutorial-12-solution.pdf) is 2^{k-p} where k = 5 (factors), p = 1, and I = ABCD how generator, wherein the D factor is confused. Thus, **D = ABC**.

```
if(!require("FrF2")) install.packages("FrF2") ; library(FrF2)

plan <- FrF2(nfactors = 5,
         nruns = 16,
         generators = "D=ABC",  # <<<
         replications = 3,
         repeat.only = T,
         randomize = FALSE)
print(plan)
```

Console:

```
...

$`generators`
[1] E=ABCD    

...
```

---

Using qualityTools package also did not get success.

```
if(!require("qualityTools")) install.packages("qualityTools") ; library(qualityTools)

plan2 <- fracDesign(k = 5,
               p = 1,
               replicates = 1,
               gen = "D = ABC")
# or gen = c("D = ABC")

runOrd(plan2) <- standOrd(plan2)
print(plan2)
```

Comment: Congrats on figuring it out yourself! However, you are allowed (and not only that, encouraged!) to answer your own question, rather than adding it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer:**

```
plan2 <- fracDesign(k = 5,
                replicates = 1,
                gen = "D = ABC")

runOrd(plan2) <- standOrd(plan2)
summary(plan2)
```